# Is it haram when I also stand up when my non-muslims pray?

Tags: halal-haram, salat

I live in a non-muslim country and I study in a catholic school and every begining of class the teacher would make us stand up and pray. The thing is, I stand up too because it our teacher would say that we should all stand up. So I just recite a surah when they're praying and I say "astaghfirullah" everytime. My question is, is it haram that I also stand up when they're praying?

Comment: Mind you that I wear hijab and they're all aware that I'm muslim

Comment: It is halal to observe, as long as your not taking part in the ritual itself and not saying anything. Talk with your teacher and ask if its okay for you to sit down since you're not catholic and they should be reasonable. Otherwise, standing up should be of no real issue.